# Add Pdf file to Resource using Code C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to add a file to an application's resources using code (not the visual designer)? I've tried the `ResourceWriter` class but it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager_members(v=vs.80).aspx) class is only used for getting resources. If you want to add or edit resources, see the MSDN page on [Adding and Editing Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx), or look at the [Resource File Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.80).aspx) for dynamically creating resource files.

Edit: The [`ResourceWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter.aspx) class will probably do what you want, too... did you read the remarks on how to use it? Generating resource files is simple, you would just have to programatically insert them into your project if that's where you wanted them ultimately.

Comment: thanks for you reply

what i want is to embed pdf file in exe file and encrypt it.

I need the output just one file as filename.exe which contains a pdf file 

does ResourceWriter help me ?? please how ???

Comment: How are you going to access this embedded PDF file? With code? Through an installer? Some other means? You have to give more detail.

Comment: I want to convert pdf to stream of bytes and encrypt it.

Comment: That has nothing to do with application resources. You need to use a `StreamReader` and some form of encryption (usually found in `System.Security.Cryptography`) if you want to do that.